# Retrieve a user name who is given maximum right answer

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch a user id who has given maximum right answer of a subject. Following are the table structure.

```
id user_id question_id answered  paper
 1  1       1           0         sub1
 2  2       1           1         sub1
 3  3       1           1         sub1
 4  1       2           1         sub1 
 5  2       2           1         sub1
 6  3       2           0         sub1
```

I try following sql to get the result but not able to figure out how I would make "2" in this sql as dynamic

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `table` 
WHERE `answered` =1 GROUP BY `paper` 
HAVING Count( `answered` ) >2
```

Got the answer

```
select `user_id` FROM table 
where answered = 1 GROUP BY paper,user_id 
HAVING Count(answered) > = (SELECT count( * ) AS count FROM table
WHERE answered =1GROUP BY paper,user_id ORDER BY count DESC Limit 1)
```

Comment: Define 'right answer'

Comment: bottom query is the right Answer

Comment: I doubt that, but good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT COUNT(answered) AS answers, user_id FROM `table` WHERE answered=1 GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY answers DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dynamic sql like this:

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM 
    -> 'SELECT `user_id` FROM `table`
    -> WHERE `answered` =1 GROUP BY `paper`
    -> HAVING Count( `answered` ) > ?'

;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared
mysql> EXECUTE stmt 
    -> USING @num
```

and finally

```
mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The other option is to create a stored procedure where you can pass your number(for eg 2) as input parameter.